# Showing the following function is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, entire-functions

Say i have the following

$$\overline{f(\overline{x+iy})} = u(x,-y) - i v(x,-y)$$

How would i show using the Cauchy Riemann equations that the above is entire, would i use the chain rule to differentiate $u$ and $v$?.

Comment: If $f(z)$ entire?

Comment: Pretty much so, provided $f$ is entire.

Comment: That's what you always do. Hope it works!

Comment: yes i am told that $f(x+iy)$ is entire in the problem, and it asks to show that $$z\mapsto \overline{f(\overline{x+iy})}$$ is entire.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143343, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644483, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102885

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the function $g(z):=\overline{f(\overline z)}$. There is another approach: If $f$ is holomorphic $\iff$ for every $z,z_0 \in \mathbb {C}$ there exists a continuous(!) function $\Delta(z)$ such that 
$$
f(z)=f(z_0)+\Delta(z)(z-z_0)
$$
Complex conjugation is continuous and that makes the whole calculation easier. Overall we get, since f is entire, that for every $z,z_0 \in \mathbb {C}$ :
$$
f(\overline{z})=f(\overline{z_0})+\Delta(\overline z)(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})
$$
Conjugating again we get that:
$$
g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}=\overline{f(\overline{z_0})}+\overline{\Delta(\overline z)}(\overline{\overline z- \overline {z_0}})=g(z_0)+\overline{\Delta(\overline z)}(z-z_0)
$$
Now the function $\overline{\Delta(\overline z)}$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions.
Using Cauchy-Riemann is an option. It is more or less applying the chainrule, Ill give you a quick example:
$$
\partial_y u(x,-y)=u_y(x,-y)(-1)=-u_y(x-y)  \\
\partial_x v(x,y)=v_x(x,-y)
$$
From that we get that, since $f$ is holomorphic, that
$$
-u_y(x-y)-v_x(x,-y)=-u_y(x-y)-(-u_y(x,-y))=0
$$
Remember to check the second equation and that $g$ is totally differentiable as a  real function!
Another notable thing is: The domain is $\mathbb{C}$. So if our function is defined and holomorphic for a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ it is also defined and holomorphic for  $\overline z \in \mathbb{C}$. This may seem trivial here, but for more general domains, it might be tricky!